# ASP.NET request extension type

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a large web application which I have recently shelved tons of *.aspx pages* from the project.

To avoid page not found error, I added these entities in the xml which came around 300+ in count. I wrote a http module that checks the request url in the xml entities and if they are found, my module is going to redirect the request to respective new pages.

Everything works great, but my collection is getting iterated for all the requests, I mean for each and every *.jpg, .css, .js, .ico, .pdf etc.*

Is there any object or property in .net that can tell the type of request that user requested for like `HttpContext.request.type`. So that I can avoid checking the request for all unwanted file types.

Comment: What version of IIS are you running?

Answer (score 2):

Yet another approach is to use ASP.NET Routing (from .NET 3.5) to create routes that map each of the old pages onto a handler for the new page.  ASP.NET routing makes it easy to have multiple Urls for a single ASPX page and you can in fact hide .ASPX completely from the end-user and have SEO friendly Urls for all your pages instead.  If you map multiple URLs onto one page you'll want to put the canonical URL tag on the page.

**Alternatively**

If you want redirects you can register routes with a simple redirect route handler like this:-

```
   routes.Add(new Route("sample.aspx", new RedirectRouteHandler("/home/newsample.aspx")));
```

And the RedirectRouteHandler might look something like this:-

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Redirect Route Handler
    /// </summary>
    public class RedirectRouteHandler : IRouteHandler
    {

    private string newUrl;

    public RedirectRouteHandler(string newUrl)
    {
        this.newUrl = newUrl;
    }

    public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        return new RedirectHandler(newUrl);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// <para>Redirecting MVC handler</para>
/// </summary>
public class RedirectHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    private string newUrl;

    public RedirectHandler(string newUrl)
    {
        this.newUrl = newUrl;
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        httpContext.Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
        httpContext.Response.StatusCode = 301;
        httpContext.Response.AppendHeader("Location", newUrl);
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: I already have those routes in place. I need redirects for those routes.

Comment: If you don't want to map them to same page (as I was suggesting) you can always register a redirect route handler as shown in my edit.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `HttpContext.Current.Request.FilePath` property which gets the virtual path of the current request.

For example, for the URL `http://www.contoso.com/virdir/page.html/tail`, the `FilePath` value is `/virdir/page.html`.

The second step is to get the extension itself. For example, you may do it using `System.IO.Path.GetExtension` method. For the `/virdir/page.html` path it'll return `.html` extension.

Answer (score 1):

You could instead catch just the 404 errors to avoid intercepting every page request.  Add an Application_Error method to your global.asax like below.  This will allow you to also redirect to a special error page if the page isn't one you need to redirect according to your XML file.

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Log.Error("*** Application_Error ***");

    Exception baseException = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();

    HttpException httpException = baseException as HttpException;
    if (httpException != null)
    {
        int httpCode = httpException.GetHttpCode();
        Log.ErrorFormat("HTTPEXCEPTION: {0} : {1}", httpCode, HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl);
        if (httpCode == 404)
        {
                 ...
```